# Code blocks are unreliable

Tags: feature-request, markdown, code-formatting, code

First of all, having to go through your code and add four spaces to every line is a pain, (even though I can just do `gg>G` in vim, I shouldn't need to launch a separate program). The code button doesn't even do anything but tell you to indent your code by hand (fail). But on top of that, the blocks hardly ever show up right. I posted a comment on StackOverflow with about four lines of code indented with precisely four spaces per line, padded above and below with a blank line, and not only did it not show up as `<pre><code>`, but **all new lines were removed**. That's just ridiculous. Are code blocks not allowed in comments? If so, that's even more ridiculous.

There has to be a better way. Github's triple-backtick option is still annoying, but it's certainly a step in the right direction. Why doesn't Stack have something like that?

Comment: Hmmm. Your question has promise, but in the end, it's just a rant. You might redeem yourself with some examples.

Comment: Clearly you didn't read the whole post; its core is an example.

Comment: Wow, quite the necromancer you are! Yep, I missed the fact that you're posting a *comment* and not a question or answer. Mea culpa. It's still a rant, and if you really cared about this feature request, you'd fix that.

Answer (score 10):

Select all the code. Press <kbd>Ctrl+K</kbd>. Alternatively, click the bracket sign (the 5th in the toolbar).

Comments only support mini-Markdown, i.e. asterisked or underscored bold/italic, links, and inline code (surround with backticks). They're not intended to be used for anything heavy, just brief notes. Click `help` next to the comment box for more info, or see [the faq](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting).